# Accesing a CSV in shinyapps

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

When I run this locally it works, however I get an error when up loading it to shinyapps.io
my csv file is a simple 10 x 10 matrix containing contents 1:100.

```
 getwd()
  # "F:/myapp"
```

Both my app.R and myappdata.csv are saved in the "myapp" folder.
I have tried the following

```
 library(DT)
 liabrary(shiny)  
 y = read.csv("myapp/myappdata.csv")
 y = read.csv("myappdata.csv")
 y = read.csv("~/myapp/myappdata.csv")
```

none of these are working. Am I saving the data wrong? The code works perfectly when I remove the y = read.csv.....

Comment: Those probably aren't valid paths once you deploy the app. It depends on what files you upload and where you place them. If app.R and myappdata.csv are uploaded into the same working directory, `read.csv("myappdata.csv")` or `read.csv("./myappdata.csv")` should work, but it depends on where your files are

Comment: hey @camille using the read.csv("./myappdata.csv") worked!! could you give some intuition there? thanks so much

Comment: also is it possible to upload a helper page for shinyapps.io to reference?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by a helper page. But you're essentially putting files (html, csv, whatever else) into a directory, and then pointing to files through their relative paths. `./file.txt` means that the file file.txt can be found in the same directory as where the code is being run. https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp

Answer (score 0):

To find out where the csv files are located, you can use the base R [`browser`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/browser) function as it allows to show code output that follows after. In your case, `browser` in combination with printing your working directory to the terminal gives you a hint on how to locate your csv file. Depending on its location, you have to specify the path.

```
browser()
print(getwd())
y <- read.csv("myappdata.csv") # modify path if needed
```